# Merging two lists of timestamps in Transact-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables containing start/end times, as so:

```
foo_events:
| foo_id | foo_event_type | start_time | end_time |

bar_events:
| bar_id | bar_event_type | start_time | end_time |
```

I want to write a `SELECT` query that returns a single list of events, with the following constraints:

1. If the end of a foo event overlaps the start of a bar event then include both events, but modify the foo_event entry end_time to be equal to the bar_event.start_time  (`CASE foo_events.start_time < bar_events.start_time AND foo_events.end_time > bar_events.start_time THEN bar_events.start_time ELSE foo_events.end_time END AS end_time`)
2. If the start time of a foo event overlaps the end of a bar event, then include both events, but modify the foo_event entry start_time to be the bar_event.end_time (`CASE foo_events.start_time < bar_events.end_time AND foo_events.end_time > bar_events.end_time THEN bar_events.end_time ELSE foo_events.start_time END AS start_time`)
3. If a foo event does not overlap with any bar events, include it in the result set unmodified (the previous two CASE statements should cover this).
4. If a foo event falls entirely within a bar event (ie: if foo_events.start_time > bar_events.start_time and foo_events.end_time < bar_events.end_time for all combinations of bar_events), do not include it in the result set.

My WIP query is below, and has the following problems:

1. There's no foreign key relationship to join on.
2. I'm not sure how to entirely exclude the foo_events entries as per point 4 above.

```
SELECT 
  CASE foo_events.start_time < bar_events.end_time AND foo_events.end_time > bar_events.end_time
  THEN
    bar_events.end_time
  ELSE 
    foo_events.start_time
  END AS start_time,
  CASE foo_events.start_time < bar_events.start_time AND foo_events.end_time > bar_events.start_time 
  THEN
    bar_events.start_time
  ELSE
    foo_events.end_time
  END AS end_time,
  --[...other columns...]
FROM foo_events 
JOIN bar_events ON [?]
```

Answer (score 1):

What comes to mind for me is to `UNION` your data since a `JOIN` really doesn't appear to be feasible.

```
WITH DATASET AS (    
    SELECT * FROM FOO_EVENTS
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM BAR_EVENTS)
```

As for point 4, I would think adding a WHERE clause to stipulate that should work:

```
SELECT * FROM DATASET
WHERE foo_events.start_time < bar_events.start_time and foo_events.end_time > bar_events.end_time
```

Then of course I believe your pre-existing SELECT statement can be plugged in. I did not create any test data to validate any of this, but hopefully this helps.